# What's the asymptotic behavior of this function at large distance?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, real-analysis, asymptotics, approximation-theory, power-series

This question is based on some Physics motivation. Define a distance function $f(\mathbf{r})=\int_{\Omega }d^2k\int_{\Omega }d^2q \cos[(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{q})\cdot\mathbf{r}]$, where $\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k},\mathbf{q}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is some finite region.

The question is: At large distance $\left | \mathbf{r} \right |\rightarrow \infty $, what's the asymptotic behavior of this function $f(\mathbf{r})$? Does it decay like $e^{-\left | \mathbf{r} \right |/L}$ or $\left | \mathbf{r} \right |^{-a}$(with some characteristic length $L$ and some positive number $a$)? Or does the large distance behavior depend on the geometry of the region $\Omega$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Simul-posted to m.se without notice to either site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526955/whats-the-asymptotic-behavior-of-this-function-at-large-distance

Comment: Simul-posting without notice. 

Comment: This is not research level - can be done analytically.  Write the cos as a sum of exponentials and separate.

Comment: @ Carl, I see,thanks. Or directly integrate cos, right?

Comment: Yes, you could use the cos addition formula and then integrate.

Comment: Now deleted from m.se by author.

Comment: @  Gerry Myerson, I have improved my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OP seems to be stuck, I give here the few lines needed to solve this problem as sugested in the comments. Given
$$
f(\mathbf{r})=\int_{\Omega }d^2k\int_{\Omega }d^2q \cos[(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{q})\cdot\mathbf{r}]=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega }d^2ke^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\int_{\Omega }d^2qe^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}}
+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega }d^2ke^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\int_{\Omega }d^2qe^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}}.
$$
These integrals are easily done to give
$$
  f(\mathbf{r})=4\frac{(1-\cos(\pi x))(1-\cos(\pi y))}{x^2y^2}
$$
from which the asymptotic behavior can be readily gotten. This makes clear that the question is not appropriate here.

Comment: @ Jon  Thanks. Does the numerator in your answer should be $(1-\cos(\pi x))(1-\cos(\pi y))$?